# cross-compile yuma123 using autotools for a MIPS target

Tags: build, cross-compiling, autotools, configure, libtool

I'm trying to cross-compile the yuma123 open source package on a Ubuntu 18.04 development system to a MIPS target, where yuma123 uses Autotools and shared libraries.

I am using a directory `INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/yuma123` as a staging area for files to be copied to the MIPS target.

The code (cross-)compiles and links without any errors using:

```
autoreconf -i -f
./configure ...
make
```

However, how do I install to `$INSTALL_PREFIX`?

Should I specify some `--prefix=` options to `./configure` as follows:

```
./configure \
    --target=mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu \
    --host=mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu \
    --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
    --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX/usr \
    --sysconfdir=$INSTALL_PREFIX/etc \
    --localstatedir=$LOCALSTATEDIR \
    --program-prefix=""
```

or should I specify `DESTDIR=` when I `sudo make install` as follows:

```
sudo make DESTDIR=$INSTALL_PREFIX install
```

What do I need to set above to ensure that `libtool` handles the `$INSTALL_PREFIX` directory correctly for shared libraries when cross-compiling in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, how do I install to `$INSTALL_PREFIX`?
>
> Should I specify some `--prefix=` options to `./configure`
>
> [...]
>
> or should I specify `DESTDIR=` when I `sudo make install`[?]

You *should* use `DESTDIR` for your use case, although in practice, it's possible that you could get away with using `--prefix`.

The `--prefix` option conveys the prefix of the intended *permanent* installation location to the Autotools.  Under some circumstances, this path or paths derived from it may end up being incorporated into the built binaries (RPATHs, config-file locations, *etc*.) or into built documentation.  This is especially true if you're using libtool.  That's obviously undesirable if the prefix is not reflective of where you intend the files actually to live on the target system.

`DESTDIR`, on the other hand,  is for *exactly* the purpose you describe: installing into a into a staging area or an alternative root.  This is what package builders generally use, for example, though I suspect that the alternative root angle was the one that originally inspired the facility.  Note, too, that if you're installing to a staging area then you probably don't need to use `sudo` to `make install`.

Comment: `sudo make DESTDIR=$INSTALL_PREFIX install` runs `/bin/bash ../../../libtool  --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c libyumamgr.la '/tmp/yuma123_install/usr/local/lib'` and I get `libtool: warning: relinking 'libyumamgr.la'` `libtool: warning: '/opt/mscc/mscc-brsdk-mips-n2e-2017.02-066/stage2/smb/x86_64-linux/usr/mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libxml2.la' seems to be moved` `libtool: error: error: relink 'libyumamgr.la' with the above command before installing it`. Should I edit the `libdir=` entry in the `*.la` file(s) or run `libtool --finish $INSTALL_PREFIX/usr/local/lib`? Any idea?

Comment: It is normal for `libtool` to complain when libraries are installed into a staging area instead of to their final destination.  This can normally be ignored, with the caveat that the libraries may not be *usable* from that staging area.  You need to put them in their final position on the target filesystem to use them. This is a "you can't have your cake and eat it too" situation.

Comment: It's unclear to me where or how the error comes in; that may be a separate issue.